# Speakers make noise while headphones are plugged in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, sound, speakers

everyone. I have a Lenovo Y400 with nvidia 750. Everytime I plug the headphones noise starts coming out through the speakers. If I stop playing music after some seconds the noise stops but when I play something again, the noise returns.

I will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. While playing with the alsamixer I scroll to the right and Disabled the option < Auto- Mut >. I don't know what's that for but know it's working fine.