# constant buzzing noise from speaker when headphones are plugged in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, sound, lenovo, alsa

I'm using Lenovo Y410p. After I plug in the headphones, there's constant buzzing noise from speaker. If I unplug them, the noise disappears.

If I disable "Auto-Mute Mode" through alsamixer, the noise disappeared immediately while the headphones are stilled plugged in. And the noise came back immediately if I enable "Auto-Mute Mode". But this is not a good solution because the feature of auto switching to headphones or speaker is gone.

Btw, my problem is similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346180/speakers-make-noise-while-headphones-are-plugged-in-ubuntu-13-04) except that the noise remains whether playing music or not.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

this happened to me.

I stops it by going into the sound settings and turning the Skype volume to 0.
I was trying to watch a Youtube video at the time and the buzzing was occurring.

you might have a program interfering with the audio your trying to listen to.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But there's only one program running(I'm listening to music online in Chrome). And the noise is from the speaker.

Comment: Reinstalling Skype from official Ubuntu repo helped me. Settings - Software&updates - sources - add "Canonical partners", `apt-get update` and `apt-get install skype`)

Comment: @VictorSergienko That worked for me. Why not submit it as an answer? I'll vote for it.

Answer (score 2):

Also have a Y410p and was having the same issue. Opening alsamixer and setting Auto-Mute Mode to disabled fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, maybe this is not the best solution but for me (lenovo Y410p) the buzzing noise apears when the keyboard back-lighting is on dim, but not when keyboard back-lighting is off or on high.

Comment: Me too, this is a very weird bug.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Skype from official Ubuntu repo helped me.

`Settings - Software&updates - sources - add "Canonical partners"`, `apt-get update` and `apt-get install skype`).

Answer (score 0):

The actual/official fix for this issue is using the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to either set the keyboard back-lighting to high or off.